# Do I need to remove the 32 bit version of Steam Beta before upgrading to the final version of Steam?

Tags: software-center, 64-bit, steam

Ok, just want to figure this out.
I have Ubuntu 12.04.1 64 Bit, and have installed the Steam Beta which was only 32 bit.
Now that is available in the software centre and now as 64 bit, I just want to find how how to get it.
Will I have to remove/purge my Beta install, then install from the software centre?
Or do I just do a software update and it will be updated?
Figure this would be a good question to ask.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are switching from 32 bit to 64 bit I recommend a purge and reinstall.  It is not very often that programs have updates which switch from 32 bit to 64 bit since some people still use 32 bit OS and the 64 bit programs won't run correctly on them.